# Undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why do I get undefined in alert() in the following code:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navigationBar = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

alert(header.innerWidth);
alert(navigationBar.innerWidth);
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #263238;
  border-bottom: solid 0.25em #37474F;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
}

.navigationBar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header" align="right">
  <div class="navigationBar" id="navigationBar">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements don't have `innerWidth`/`innerHeight`. You might have wanted `offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight`, or `getComputedStyle(x).width`/`height` (which will give you a string, almost certainly ending in `px`, for the outer width of the element).

Also note [Kuldeep Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861542/157247) about `clientWidth`/`clientHeight`.

Example (without `clientWidth`/`clientHeight`):

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navigationBar = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

console.log(header.offsetWidth);
console.log(navigationBar.offsetWidth);
console.log(getComputedStyle(header).width);
console.log(getComputedStyle(navigationBar).width);
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #263238;
  border-bottom: solid 0.25em #37474F;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
}

.navigationBar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header" align="right">
  <div class="navigationBar" id="navigationBar">

  </div>
</div>
```

(On old IE, instead of `getComputedStyle(x)`, you'd use `x.currentStyle`.)

Answer (score 6):

It's because DOM elements don't have an innerWidth and innerHeight. That's a window property.

Answer (score 2):

try **clientWidth** instead of innerWidth                                 .

Comment: Became a working draft exactly a year ago: https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-element-clientwidth

Answer (score 0):

There is no innerWidth on elements, that's a jQuery function.  Instead, look for clientWidth:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var header = document.getElementById("header");
      var navigationBar = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
      var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

      console.log(
         header.clientWidth,
         navigationBar.clientWidth
         );
    });
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #263238;
  border-bottom: solid 0.25em #37474F;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
}

.navigationBar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header" align="right">
  <div class="navigationBar" id="navigationBar" ></div>
</div>
```